# How to change the attributes passed to a function within a class in python

Tags: python, class, attributes, declaration

it's probably my OCD, but I've written some code and I was just wondering if there was an elegant way of changing the attributes passed to a function within a class in python? I have some example code below (I'm trying to change the value of on_message):

```
# my_class is defined in an external library

class my_class: 
    def __init__(self, stream_url="wss://stream.default:6969/ws", on_message=None):
        super().__init__(stream_url, on_message=on_message)
        
    def my_function(self, key: str, **kwargs):
        # do stuff to key and kwargs

# my python code

ws_client = my_class(stream_url="wss://stream.actual:6969/ws") # this is at the top of the file where all other declarations are made, as there is no on_message value passed to the class, it's value is None as per __init__ function

def do_stuff_with_message(): # this happens about 3/4 through
    # do stuff to with the message

ws_client = my_class(on_message=do_stuff_with_message) # this works but seems clumsy and like a redeclaration. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

ws_client.my_function(key="Dante")
```

As stated, the code works, I'm just looking for a neater solution, perhaps even a forward declaration of do_stuff_with_message. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what is it actually you are trying to achieve. Do you want the `ws_client` in both cases to be the same object, but change some of its attributes?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what the parent class does with the `on_message` that is given to its `__init__`. Does the parent class provide a way of changing this on an existing object, either with an explicit setter function or just by updating an attribute value?

Comment: *perhaps even a forward declaration of do_stuff_with_message* Worst case, you could have the logic of `do_stuff_with_message` depend on some global variable as a flag. Then you set up your client with `on_message=do_stuff_with_message` from the start, and change the flag variable when you want to change the behaviour.

Comment: @slothrop - Apologies for the unclear explanation, ws_client to be the same object, with attributes passed to a function within the class changed. Pretty sure that __init__ assigns None to on_message if nothing is passed to my_class on declaration, trying to change None to do_stufff_with_message. How would I set up the logic of do_stuff_with_message to depend on some global variable as a flag? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for you assistance and comments. I managed to "fix" it with (a kind of forward declaration):

```
# my_class is defined in an external library

class my_class: 
def __init__(self, stream_url="wss://stream.default:6969/ws", on_message=None):
    super().__init__(stream_url, on_message=on_message)
    
def my_function(self, key: str, **kwargs):
    # do stuff to key and kwargs   

# my python code

def Do_Stuff_With_Message():
    do_stuff_with_message()

ws_client = my_class(stream_url="wss://stream.actual:6969/ws", on_message=Do_Stuff_With_Message) # this is at the top of the file where all other declarations are made, as there is no on_message value passed to the class, it's value is None as per __init__ function

def do_stuff_with_message(): # this happens about 3/4 through
    # do stuff to with the message

ws_client.my_function(key="Dante")
```

Once again, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, it looks like your are overwriting `ws_client` with a new instance of your class in `ws_client = my_class(on_message=do_stuff_with_message)`. If you'd like to add or change an attribute, you can use `ws_client.on_message = do_stuff_with_message`.

Also, `super().__init__` is used to initialize a parent class when inheriting. You are not doing this here, so it is not needed.

```py
class my_class: 
    def __init__(self, stream_url="wss://stream.default:6969/ws"):
        # super().__init__(stream_url, on_message=on_message) does not do anything as my_class is not inheriting from another class
        self.stream_url = stream_url
        
    def my_function(self, key: str, **kwargs):
        # do stuff to key and kwargs

ws_client = my_class(stream_url="wss://stream.actual:6969/ws")

def do_stuff_with_message():
    # do stuff to with the message

ws_client.on_message = do_stuff_with_message # on_message does not need to be declared in __init__.
                                             # In your original code you created a new instance or your class. This code modifies the existing object

ws_client.my_function(key="Dante")
```

Comment: *"If you'd like to add or change an attribute, you can use ws_client.on_message = do_stuff_with_message"* We don't know that the class has a settable attribute `on_message`.

Comment: *"Also, super().__init__ is used to initialize a parent class when inheriting. You are not doing this here, so it is not needed."* I suspect we are inheriting, and this is what OP means by the comment "my_class is defined in an external library". Although the code provided in the question doesn't show a parent class, so it's not quite clear what we are seeing.

Comment: @slothrop The only way the class would not allow setting an attribute is if __setattr__() is overwritten to block it in some way. There is no indication that this is the case.

Comment: Not so, for example a `@property` with no setter.

Comment: We don't even know for sure that the parent class stores `on_message` as an attribute, only that it accepts it as an argument to `__init__`. It could store it with a different name, or it might not store it as a class attribute at all.

Comment: Sorry Brady, but that doesn't work. My understanding is that if on_message is an attribute of the object, it would work, but that's not the case. It's an attribute that is passed to a function, within the object. I can't change the class as it originates from a library. Thanks though.